# Error "INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '@nombretbl'" tratando de hacer consulta con nombre de tabla dinámico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola Amigos estoy intentando generar varias tablas en Sql, que saldrán de una tabla base.

Ejemplo: Tengo una tabla BONUS que puede contener mayor o menor a 4 millones de registros; y tengo una tabla CONTEO_CUENTA, donde están las cantidades de registros por cuentas(campo auxc_cuenta de tbl BONUS); y lo que intento hacer es separar en tablas (CON EL NOMBRE DE LA CUENTA O DEL ITEM) la información de BONUS dependiendo de la cantidad de registros en AUXC_CUENTA.

[image: TABLA CONTEO_CUENTA]

```
Declare @suma int ,@conteo1 int, @item1 int, @item2 int, @nombretbl varchar(100)
Set @conteo1=600000
Set @suma=(SELECT SUM(conteo) from CONTEO_CUENTA where conteo<@conteo1)
set @item1=1 

IF @suma<4000000
    BEGIN
        SELECT BONUS.* INTO CUENTA_0 FROM BONUS WHERE AUXC_CUENTA IN(SELECT AUXC_CUENTA FROM CONTEO_CUENTA WHERE CONTEO<@conteo1) 
        set @item2=(select top 1 dbo.CONTEO_CUENTA.ITEM from CONTEO_CUENTA where CONTEO<@conteo1 order by ITEM asc) 
        While (@item1<=@item2)
        Begin
        Set @nombretbl =  'CUENTA_'+'['+CAST(@ITEM1 AS VARCHAR(30))+']' --(select auxc_cuenta from CONTEO_CUENTA where ITEM = @item1)
        SELECT BONUS.* INTO @nombretbl FROM dbo.BONUS WHERE AUXC_CUENTA=(select dbo.CONTEO_CUENTA.AUXC_CUENTA FROM CONTEO_CUENTA WHERE ITEM=@item1)
        END
        set @item1 = @item1 + 1
        End
Else
    Begin
        set @conteo1=500000
        SELECT BONUS.* INTO CUENTA_0 FROM BONUS WHERE AUXC_CUENTA IN(SELECT AUXC_CUENTA FROM CONTEO_CUENTA WHERE CONTEO<@conteo1) 
        set @item2=(select top 1 dbo.CONTEO_CUENTA.ITEM from CONTEO_CUENTA where CONTEO<@conteo1 order by item asc)
        While (@item1<=@item2)
        Begin
        Set @nombretbl= (select auxc_cuenta from CONTEO_CUENTA where ITEM = @item1)
        SELECT BONUS.* INTO @nombretbl FROM BONUS WHERE AUXC_CUENTA=(select dbo.CONTEO_CUENTA.AUXC_CUENTA FROM CONTEO_CUENTA WHERE ITEM=@item1)
        set @item1 = @item1 + 1
        End
    End
    select count(*) from CUENTA_0
```

Pero hay un problema con la variable `@nombretbl`, me sale:

> INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '@nombretbl'

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: UPS, LO SIENTO; lo que pasa es que me muestra error en la variable @nombretbl

Comment: que error muestra?

Comment: hay un problema con la variable @nombretbl, me sale INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR '@nombretbl'

Comment: cabe indicar que si me crea la tabla **cuenta_0** que es la de todas las cuentas menores a 600mil, pero cuando intento hacer el otro query a del otro bloque que deseo que sea una tabla por item, al parecer hay un problema con la variable @nombretbl

Comment: ohh, ok esta bien, gracias de todas maneras.

Comment: Ok sstan, Gracias. de igual forma intentare solucionarlo :)

Answer (score 2):

El problema es cuando haces:

```
SELECT BONUS.* INTO @nombretbl FROM ...
```

No puedes usar una variable donde corresponde un nombre de tabla.

Para hacer lo que deseas, debes usar SQL dinámico:

```
declare @dynamicSQL nvarchar(200);

...

set @dynamicSQL = 'SELECT BONUS.* INTO ' + @nombretbl + ' FROM dbo.BONUS WHERE AUXC_CUENTA=(select dbo.CONTEO_CUENTA.AUXC_CUENTA FROM CONTEO_CUENTA WHERE ITEM=@item1)';
exec sp_executesql @dynamicSQL, N'@item1 int', @item1 = @item1;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, lo probare en el código para ver que sale.